# Agregar keyup a un input cuando este se crea por javascript y no por html

Tags: javascript, html5

En JavaScript estoy creando un `input` y le voy agregando clases. Quiero agregarle un `keyup`.

```
// Creacion de input para "monto"
var monto_inp = document.createElement("input");
monto_inp.name = "monto";
monto_inp.placeholder = "Monto";
monto_inp.classList.add('detalle_pago');
monto_inp.classList.add('monto');
```

Comment: Sería interesante que formateases bien tu código con las etiquetas <code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si unicamente quieres agregarle a ese elemento, puedes hacerlo de esta forma,
el selector $ de jquery acepta elementos dinámicos.

```
// Creacion de input para "monto"
var monto_inp = document.createElement("input");
monto_inp.name = "monto";
monto_inp.placeholder = "Monto";
monto_inp.classList.add('detalle_pago');
monto_inp.classList.add('monto');
$(monto_inp).on('keyup', function() {
        alert('key up');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Un evento en Javascript se agrega con *addEventListener*:

```
monto_inp.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    // lo que sea que quieras hacer en el keyup
});
```

O así:

```
monto_inp.onkeyup = function(e) {
    // lo que sea que quieras hacer en el keyup
});
```

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a la respuesta de @Dibort para crear el evento `onkeyup` es necesario con solo llamar el `item` en este caso `monto_inp` y agregar el `evento` como lo ves a continuación.

```js
function createInput() {
    // Creacion de input para "monto"
    var monto_inp = document.createElement("input");
    monto_inp.id = "idInput";
    monto_inp.name = "monto";
    monto_inp.placeholder = "Monto";
    monto_inp.type = "text";
    monto_inp.classList.add('detalle_pago');
    monto_inp.classList.add('monto');
    document.body.appendChild(monto_inp);
    monto_inp.onkeyup = function() {console.log("onkeyup en input");};
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    </head>
    <body >
         <button onclick="createInput()">Crear input</button>
    </body>
</html>
```